# PyDev can't recognize all module members correctly

Tags: python-3.x, ide, pydev

I have two examples:

[image]

As you can see PyDev marks Process in first example and PULL in second as "Undefined variable from import (...)". **However, code is executed without any problems. It's just PyDev can't resolve those names.**

Taking a closer look on multiprocessing and zmq modules I found that members that can't be recognized are imported in some weird way by updating globals.

Is there a way to make PyDev evaluate those import files more thoroughly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can ask PyDev to analyze modules through a shell.

See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for more details (mostly the forced builtins part).

Answer (score 1):

This has been a real pain with getting PyDev to recognize all the objects from pyzmq. As Fabio suggests via the link, set zmq as a forced built-in and it should solve the issue. I'm using zmq with gevent so in my case I import zmq as follows ...

> import zmq.green as zmq

Using the latest PyDev in Eclipse: Windows > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter > Forced Builtins > New.

Just add zmq for "Builtin to add". I would close the project(s) and restart Eclipse. You may need to close / reopen the module(s) showing the errors and / or do a Project > clean. The zmq errors should go away.